# what the benefit of convenience initializer if do same job with initialize the class members with default values

Tags: swift

I am reading Designated Initializers with default values and convenience initializer and I am a little bit confused about them. If I can achieve every thing with Initializer with default values then why one should create convenience initializer.

I have created an example in both scenario and compare them.

**Initializer with Default Values:**

```
class Cat {

var color:String
var age:Int

init(color:String = "black",age:Int = 1) {
    self.color = color
    self.age = age
}

}
```

**Convenience Initializer:**

```
class Cat {
 var color: String
 var age: Int

 //If both parameters color and age are given:
 init (color: String, age: Int) {
      self.color = color
      self.age = age
 }

//If only age is given:
 convenience init (age: Int) {
      self.init(color: "black", age: age)
 }

 //if only color is given:
 convenience init (color: String) {
      self.init(color: color, age: 1)
 }

 //if nothing given
 convenience init () {
      self.init(color: "black", age: 1)
 }

}
```

**Initializer varient calling:**

//create Otto:

```
var Otto = Cat(color: "white", age: 10)
print("Otto is \(Otto.color) and \(Otto.age) year(s) old!")
```

//create Muffins:

```
var Muffins = Cat(age: 5)
print("Muffins is \(Muffins.color) and \(Muffins.age) year(s) old!")
```

//create Bruno:

```
var Bruno = Cat(color: "red")
print("Bruno is \(Bruno.color) and \(Bruno.age) year(s) old!")
```

//create Pico:

```
var Pico = Cat()
print("Pico is \(Pico.color) and \(Pico.age) year(s) old!")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because sometimes initialising a class isn't that straightforward. Let's look at this `Rectangle` class. It has a `width` and `height`:

```
class Rectangle {
    let width: Double
    let height: Double

    init(width: Double, height: Double) {
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
    }
}
```

Here, you can add a convenience initialiser that takes a `sideLength` parameter:

```
convenience init(sideLength: Double) {
    self.init(width: sideLength, height: sideLength)
}
```

Or, a convenience initializer that takes a `aFourthOf` parameter:

```
convenience init(aFourthOf rect: Rectangle) {
    self.init(width: rect.width / 2, height: rect.height / 2)
}
```

There are lots of these situations.

Answer (score 0):

That is a very interesting question.

You can always initialize using designated initializers but as the name suggests it ease the initialization when there are some complications or rare scenarios. 
Here are a couple of examples

**1.** Look at the example below,

```
 class Cat {
       var color: String
       var age: Int

 //If both parameters color and age are given:
 init (color: String, age: Int) {
      self.color = color
      self.age = age
 }

 //If only age is provided:
 convenience init (age: Int) {
      self.init(color: "black", age: age)
 }

 //if only color is provided:
 convenience init (color: String) {
      self.init(color: color, age: 1)
 }

 //if nothing is provided
 convenience init () {
      self.init(color: "black", age: 1)
 }
}
```

**2.** While creating a storyboard instance we need to specify **Name** & **Bundle**. Since the bundle is Optional you can specify it as nil. Additionally, if you don't specify the bundle then XCode gives you a warning. But doing this every time for no reason becomes irritating.

[image]

You can't change the default init method for the UIStoryboard class. What should you do?? Simple create an extension to UIStoryboard and use a convenience initializer.

This way convenience initializer helps you code better.

[image]

As we observed above that there can be multiple cases during development where we need to add custom initialization. One important thing to keep in mind is **Designated initializers must always delegate up (to base/super class).
Convenience initializers must always delegate across.**